# Function overloading with reference classes in R?

Tags: r, oop, overloading

Here is my attempt:

```
MyClass = setRefClass("MyClass", fields = c("x", "y"))
MyClass$methods(
    myadd = function() {
        x + y
    }
)
MyClass$methods(
    myadd = function(n) {
        x + y + n
    }
)
MyClass$methods(
    initialize = function(xinit, yinit) {
        x <<- xinit
        y <<- yinit
    }
)

myobj = MyClass(2, 3)
myobj$myadd()
```

It failed miserably of course:

```
Error in myobj$myadd() (from #3) : argument "n" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the R-ish way to do that is with a default parameter to your method. Something like:

```
MyClass = setRefClass("MyClass", fields = c("x", "y"))
MyClass$methods(
  myadd = function(n=0) {
      x + y + n
  }
)
MyClass$methods(
  initialize = function(xinit, yinit) {
      x <<- xinit
      y <<- yinit
  }
)
```

Now, you'll get what I think you expect:

```
myobj = MyClass(2, 3)
myobj$myadd()
[1] 5

myobj$myadd(5)
[1] 10
```

At risk of being called a "Hadley Wickham fanboy" (again!), a great source of info about the R object system is the [OO section](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#rc) of Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/).

For what it's worth, if you *do* need to implement methods with complicated dispatching, the [S4 object system](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Genolini-S4tutorialV0-5en.pdf) offers quite a bit of power, but perhaps at the cost of some additional complexity and verbosity.